# Error reading from 192.168.1.164:44214: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

i got this error when i am trying to connect peers running in different machines .I found this error in  docker logs of orderer.There is an  error in docker logs of peer2 running in different machine

**Failed obtaining connection: Could not connect to any of the endpoints: [orderer.example.com:7050]**

Comment: try giving the ip address of the machine `::::7050` on which orderer is running and make sure that tls is enabled in both `orderer.yaml` and `core.yaml`

Comment: Thanks for your help.It has worked @rohit_sethi

Comment: do i need to modify the orderer.yaml and core.yaml ?If yes can u guide me how to do that as i dont have any external orderer.yaml file in file system.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the `orderer.yaml` file at `fabric-samples/config` folder.
Going through the fields and their respective comments in `orderer.yaml` and `core.yaml` can help you to understand the method of configuring the network(orderer/peer).

And [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/enable_tls.html) you can get the info related to TLS.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But i have already given the tls enabled and required keys and certificates in peers and orderer in docker files.Do i need to modify the core.yaml and orderer.yaml as i didnt find any link that firstnetwork in fabric samples is using config folder's files @rohit_sethi

Comment: As mentioned in link send by you, i have added tls enabled certificates and keys in peers and orderer containers

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ? please share detailed info

Comment: I am working on multi organisation network setup using first network of fabric samples.one of the organisation say org1 has created a channel by passing tls certs of orderer ,the other organisation org2 has to fetch the  channel created by org1 and join the peers into the channel.when i do fetch action using peer channel fetch by passing tls certs  of orderer ,i got the error like ""connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 98.124.199.121:7050: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting..."".

Comment: and in orderer logs ,i got error as :TLS handshake failed with error tls: client didn't provide a certificate {"server": "Orderer", "remote address": "172.24.0.4:49608"}

Comment: `CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt`
      - `CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.key`
      - `CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt`

set these environment variables and then try again

Comment: Yeah i have already tried with above environment variables.After following that i got the above error